# How to crawl multiple-level pages to one item in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

All examples I found of Scrapy talk about how to crawl a single page, or how to crawl multiple-level pages, when each of the deepest pages is saved as an independent `Item`. But my situation is a bit more complex.

For example, the website structure is:

```
A (List page of books)
--> B (Book summary page)
----> C (Book review pages)
----> D (Book download pages)
```

And so the definition of the `Item` looks like:

```py
class BookItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    type = scrapy.Field()
    introduction = scrapy.Field()
    resources = scrapy.Field() # To be a list of ResourceItem
    reviews = scrapy.Field() # To be a list of ReviewItem

# Download pages
class ResourceItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    createDate = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()


# Book reviews
class ReviewItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    createDate = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    content = scrapy.Field()
```

How could I complete all fields of `BookItem`? I *do* know that I can write 4 methods, like `parse_A()`,`parse_B()`,`parse_C()` and `parse_D()`, and Scrapy allows them to be a workflow by using `yield scrapy.Request()` at the end of each methods.

But what should I return in the deepest methods, i.e. `parse_C()` and `parse_D()`?

1. If I return a `ResourceItem` or `ReviewItem`, it will be saved directly.
2. If I return the `BookItem` from upper methods, the uncompleted item will be saved directly, too.
3. If I return a `Request` for `parse_D()` in `parse_C()`, it will not work either, because resources may be empty (that is to say, there may be **no links of C** on B pages at all). So `parse_C()` won't be called, leaving `parse_D()` uncalled, and D fields unfilled in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer it by myself now.

Just **`yield None`** or **omit return statements** in `parse_C()` and `parse_D()` will solve the problem.

#### Some explanation

Scrapy will not close the spider *simply* because one of the callbacks returns nothing, but ensure that there is no new one in the request queue as well.

So, since `parse_B()` will not return `None` or `Item` before it completes yielding all of its requests of Subpage C & D, the workflow won't be interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some data around using `meta` parameters (see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html).

So you can populate your item in multiple requests/parse functions.

Quick example to show the logic:

```
def parse_summary(self, response):
  book_item = # scrape book item here
  reviews_url = # extract reviews url 
  resources_url = # extract resources url
  return scrapy.Request(reviews_url, callback=self.parse_reviews, meta={'item': book_item, 'resources_url': resources_url })

def parse_reviews(self, response):
  book_item = response.meta.get('item') # get item draft
  book_item.reviews = # extract reviews here
  resources_url = response.meta.get('resources_url')
  return scrapy.Request(resources_url, callback=self.parse_resources, meta={'item': book_item })

def parse_resources(self, response):
  book_item = response.meta.get('item') # get item draft
  book_item.ressources = # extract ressources here
  return book_item # once completed, return the item
```

Hope you get the idea (I'm not really confident on the code execution, just wrote it down without testing).

Comment: Thanks Yall, but I _know_ that I can pass down the uncompleted items with `meta` (and fill the fields in downstream methods). However, my problem is that whether `parse_reviews` and `parse_resources` could be somehow 'parallel' to each other, as was pointed out in the third question.